# XAML UI slow using Observable collection MVVM

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp

this is my first question. I have read topics related to my question but didn't find a solution.

There are 10 objects holding an array of buttons bound to an observable collection in my MainViewModel. I want to switch between the objects to show the current object.
Updating the ui is slow this way. I'm not sure what I can try.

EDIT: I tried to create a
Minimal, Reproducible Example:
Name od the Project: STACK_MVVM

Mainpage.xaml

```
<Page
x:Class="STACK_MVVM.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:STACK_MVVM"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Grid x:Name="thegrid" Margin="0,0,0,0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <controls:UniformGrid x:Name="ButtonsUniformGrid"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"  Orientation="Horizontal"  Columns="16" Rows="5"  ColumnSpacing="4" RowSpacing="4">
    </controls:UniformGrid>
    <controls:UniformGrid x:Name="ButtonsUniformGrid_Copy"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"  Orientation="Horizontal"  Columns="10" Rows="3"  ColumnSpacing="4" RowSpacing="4" Margin="0,15,0,0">

    </controls:UniformGrid>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;



namespace STACK_MVVM
{

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public Room[] room = new Room[10];
    public ToggleButton[] channelSel = new ToggleButton[10];
    Binding[] myChanSel_Binding_Command = new Binding[10];
    public MainViewModel TheMainViewModel1 { get; set; }
    int tabentry = 0;
    public MyLogic TheLogic = null;
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.TheMainViewModel1 = new MainViewModel();
        this.TheMainViewModel1.fillItems();
         TheLogic = new MyLogic();
         TheLogic.setTheMainModel(TheMainViewModel1);


        ButtonsUniformGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        ButtonsUniformGrid_Copy.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
        ButtonsUniformGrid_Copy.Columns = 16;
        ButtonsUniformGrid_Copy.Rows = 4;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            room[i] = new Room();
            room[i].channel = i;
            TheLogic.setTheModels(room[i].TheMainViewModel1, i);
            thegrid.Children.Add(room[i].uniformGrid1);

            Grid.SetColumn(room[i].uniformGrid1, 1);     //ToggleButtonMatrix
            Grid.SetRow(room[i].uniformGrid1, 1);

            //****
            channelSel[i] = new ToggleButton();
            channelSel[i].HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
            channelSel[i].VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
            channelSel[i].Checked += HandleChannelSelChecked;
            channelSel[i].Tag = i;

            channelSel[i].SetBinding(ToggleButton.CommandProperty, new Binding() { Source = TheMainViewModel1, Path = new PropertyPath("OKButtonClicked1") });
            channelSel[i].SetBinding(ToggleButton.CommandParameterProperty, new Binding() { Source = TheMainViewModel1, Path = new PropertyPath("MyChannel[" + i + "]") });

            ButtonsUniformGrid_Copy.Children.Add(channelSel[i]);
        }

    }
    private void HandleChannelSelChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)   // make it Visible
    {
        ToggleButton toggle = sender as ToggleButton;
        int m = (int)toggle.Tag;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (i != m)
            {
                room[i].uniformGrid1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                channelSel[i].IsChecked = false;
            }
        }
        room[m].uniformGrid1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
}
```

Room.cs

```
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;

namespace STACK_MVVM
{
    public class Room
    {
        public UniformGrid uniformGrid1 = new UniformGrid();
        public Dictionary<ToggleButton, Tuple<int, int>> clientDict = new Dictionary<ToggleButton, Tuple<int, int>>();
        public ToggleButton[,] bu = new ToggleButton[5, 16];
        public int channel;

        public struct pattern
        {
            public int[,] vec_bs1;
            public int[] vec_bs;
        };
        public pattern thepattern = new pattern();
        public MainViewModel TheMainViewModel1 { get; set; }
        Binding[] Toggle_Binding = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.Binding[5 * 16];

    public Room()
    {
        TheMainViewModel1 = new MainViewModel();
        TheMainViewModel1.fillItems();
        thepattern.vec_bs1 = new int[5, 16];
        thepattern.vec_bs = new int[80 * 10];

        uniformGrid1.Columns = 16;
        uniformGrid1.Rows = 5;
        uniformGrid1.ColumnSpacing = 4;
        uniformGrid1.RowSpacing = 4;
        uniformGrid1.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
        uniformGrid1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
            {
                bu[i, j] = new ToggleButton();

                clientDict.Add(bu[i, j], new Tuple<int, int>(i, j));
                bu[i, j].HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
                bu[i, j].VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;                
                uniformGrid1.Children.Add(bu[i, j]);
                //BINDINGS
                Toggle_Binding[(j) + (i * 16)] = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.Binding();
                Toggle_Binding[(j) + (i * 16)].Source = this.TheMainViewModel1;
                string ppath = "MyItemsbool[" + ((j) + (i * 16)) + "]";
                Toggle_Binding[(j) + (i * 16)].Path = new PropertyPath(ppath);
                Toggle_Binding[(j) + (i * 16)].Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
                Toggle_Binding[(j) + (i * 16)].UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
                BindingOperations.SetBinding(bu[i, j], ToggleButton.IsCheckedProperty, Toggle_Binding[(j) + (i * 16)]);

            }
        }
    }
    private void HandleToggleButtonUnChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       ToggleButton toggle = sender as ToggleButton;
       var client = clientDict[sender as ToggleButton];
       // Debug.WriteLine(client.Item1 + " " + client.Item2);
        thepattern.vec_bs1[client.Item1, client.Item2] = 0;
    }
    public void HandleToggleButtonChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ToggleButton toggle = sender as ToggleButton;
        var client = clientDict[sender as ToggleButton];
       // Debug.WriteLine(client.Item1 + " " + client.Item2);
        this.thepattern.vec_bs1[client.Item1, client.Item2] = 1;
    }
}//Class
}
```

MyLogic.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace STACK_MVVM
{   public class MyLogic
   {
        public static MainViewModel[] TheModels = new MainViewModel[10];
        public MainViewModel TheMainModel = new MainViewModel();

        public void setTheModels(MainViewModel themodel, int num)
        {
            TheModels[num] = themodel;
            //Debug.WriteLine("THEMODELS" + TheModels[0].MyItemsbool[0]);
        }
        public void setTheMainModel(MainViewModel themainmodel)
        {
            TheMainModel = themainmodel;
        }
        public static void LoadPattern(object parameter)
        {
           for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
           {
                TheModels[x].pattern_load_struct((int)parameter);
           }
            Debug.Write("CHANNELNUM: " + parameter);
        }
   }
}
```

MainViewModelBase.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Core;
using Windows.UI.Core;

namespace STACK_MVVM
{
    public abstract class MainViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private CoreDispatcher _dispatcher = CoreApplication.MainView.Dispatcher;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (_dispatcher.HasThreadAccess)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
            else
            {
                _dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                {
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace STACK_MVVM
{
    public class MainViewModel : MainViewModelBase
    {
        public struct pattern
        {   
            public int[] vec_bs1;
            public int[] vec_bs;
        };
        public pattern thepattern = new pattern();

        private ObservableCollection<int> _myChannel = new ObservableCollection<int>(new[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 });
        private ObservableCollection<bool> _myItemsbool = new ObservableCollection<bool>(new[] { true, false, true });    
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            thepattern.vec_bs1 = new int[5 * 16];
            thepattern.vec_bs = new int[80 * 10];
        }
        public ObservableCollection<bool> MyItemsbool
        {
            get { return _myItemsbool; }
            set
            {
                _myItemsbool = value;
            }
        }
        public ObservableCollection<int> MyChannel { get => _myChannel; set => _myChannel = value; }
        public void fillItems()
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
                {
                    {

                        MyItemsbool.Add(true);
                        MyItemsbool[(j) + (i * 16)] = true;
                        //MyItemsbool[(j) + (i * 16)] = rnd.Next(2) !=0;
                    }
                }
        }
        public ICommand OKButtonClicked1
        {
            get
            {
               return new DelegateCommand1<object>(MyLogic.LoadPattern);
            }
        }

       public void pattern_save_struct(int tabentry)
       {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
                {
                    thepattern.vec_bs[(j) + (i * 16) + ((80) * tabentry)] = (MyItemsbool[(j) + (i * 16)]) ? 1 : 0;
                    //  thepattern.vec_bs[(j) + (i * 16) + ((80) * tabentry)] = thepattern.vec_bs1[i, j];   
                    // thepattern.vec_bs[(j) + (i * 16) + ((80) * tabentry)] = thepattern.vec_bs1[i, j];   
                }
            }
       }
        public async Task pattern_load_struct(int tabentry)
        {
            var rnd = new Random();  //this is just for testing - Randomly Activate Cell

                await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                Array.Copy(thepattern.vec_bs, 80 * tabentry, thepattern.vec_bs1, 0, 80);
                // Array.Copy(thepattern.vec_bs1, 0, MyItemsbool, 0, 80); //DONT WORK

                for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++)
                {
                     thepattern.vec_bs1[i] = rnd.Next(2);            // Randomly activate Cell - this line can be deletet.

                    MyItemsbool[i] = thepattern.vec_bs1[i] != 0;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

DelegateCommand1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace STACK_MVVM
{
    class DelegateCommand1<T> : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Action<T> handler;
        private bool isEnabled = true;
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
        public delegate void SimpleEventHandler();
        public DelegateCommand1(Action<T> handler)
        {
            this.handler = handler;
        }
        public bool IsEnabled
        {
            get
            {
                return this.isEnabled;
            }
        }
        void ICommand.Execute(object org)
        {
            this.handler((T)org);
        }
        bool ICommand.CanExecute(object org)
        {
            return this.IsEnabled;
        }
        private void OnCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            if (this.CanExecuteChanged != null)
            {
                this.CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `async void` ?  Did you try using `async Task` instead ?  I am assuming `async void` is not the top level event handler here.

Comment: I'm a bloody beginner in C#. I tried your suggestion but that doesn't change the laggy behaviour of updating the UI.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I cannot create a demo based on the code you provided. Can you provide a [minimum runnable demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can test and find out what the problem is.

Comment: @Richard Zhang - MSFT I have created a git repo with the code example above, too. https://github.com/sensn/STACK_MVVM

Comment: I think maybe it is because of for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++) {
                                                      MyItemsbool[i] = thepattern.vec_bs1[i] != 0;}                MyItemsbool is the observable collection, and i only want to update one element of it. Maybe it does update all of the togglebuttons every iteration of the loop. I don't really get how ObservableCollection works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at your code and you seem to have created all the controls (including `UniformGrid` and a lots of `ToggleButton`s) in the C# code and filled them into the UI when needed.

This is actually a huge overhead for the system and it is not convenient to debug.

Your problem is that it does not follow the design pattern of MVVM. In MVVM, please do not to create controls directly in C# code, but operate it with data class (`Model`).

The `View` in MVVM(Model, View, View-Model) can be regarded as a `DataTemplate` in UWP. The recommended method is as follows:

1. Create a class for `room` and a class for `apartment`:

```cs
public class Room
{
    public bool IsOpened { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Apartment
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
}
```

2. Create a `DataTemplate` in `MainPage.xaml` and use the binding to bind the corresponding properties.

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Room" x:Key="RoomItemTemplate">
        <ToggleButton IsChecked="{x:Bind IsOpened}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Apartment" x:Key="ApartmentItemTemplate">
        <ToggleButton Content="{x:Bind Name}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

3. Use `GridView` to bind collections.

**xaml**

```xml
...
<GridView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource RoomItemTemplate}"
          x:Name="RoomGridView"
          />

<GridView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ApartmentItemTemplate}"
          x:Name="ApartmentGridView"
          IsItemClickEnabled="True"
          ItemsSource="{x:Bind ApartmentCollection}"
          ItemClick="ApartmentGridView_ItemClick"/>
...
```

**xaml.cs**

```cs
public ObservableCollection<Apartment> ApartmentCollection = new ObservableCollection<Apartment>();
//...
private void ApartmentGridView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var item = e.ClickedItem as Apartment;
    RoomGridView.ItemsSource = item.Rooms;
}
```

---

It should be noted that the above code is simplified code. If you want to migrate the current code to this mode, you need to reorganize your code.

With GridView, you can use the virtualization of the control itself to reduce resource consumption. At the same time, this DataTemplate method can greatly simplify the code writing.

Regarding what you said to change the state of a single item, `ObservableCollection` has no response. This is normal, because `ObservableCollection` only responds to changes in the number of items in the collection. If you want to notify the UI when changing the properties of the data class, you need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface for the Model.

---

Here are some documents that might help you:

- [Data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-quickstart)
- [Data binding and MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-and-mvvm)
- [Xaml Bind Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlBind)

---

**Update**

If the `GridView` is still stuck, this may be caused by its default animation calculation. You can use `ItemsControl` to solve this problem.

```xml
<ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource RoomItemTemplate}"
  x:Name="RoomGridView"
          Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <controls:UniformGrid Columns="16" Rows="5" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll study this and try to create a proper MVVM version of my programm following your recommendations. The reason i created the controls in code-behind is that i have 80 buttons per room object, and i didn't want to create 80 buttons in Xaml. Morover i wanted to have the option to make the number of togglbuttons dynamic. I have to study your pattern now. Thanks!

Comment: I understand your needs, `GridView` or `ListView` is prepared for this.

Comment: If someone else tries the code: I had to add IsItemClickEnabled="True" to xaml before ItemClick="ApartmentGridView_ItemClick"/> to make it work. But still the Button eats up the ItemclickEvent. So you have to click the rectange around it. @Richard Zhang - MSFT This technique seems to be very promising. I hope I can make the whole thing addaptive too. That was why I was using Uniformgrid. Maybe I just have to put the Gridview into a Cell of UniformGrid? Will it scale if I make the window fullscreen. Anyway thanks again for your help!

Comment: Sorry, this is my oversight, and now I have modified the answer. In addition, if you need to get the currently selected data class when you click the `ToggleButton`, you can use this code snippet in the Click event `var data = (sender as ToggleButton).DataContext as Apartment`. As for `UniformGrid`, I recommend you use `StaggeredPanel` in WindowsCommunityToolkit, which can be used with `GridView` better.

Comment: "I looked at your code and you seem to have created all the controls (including UniformGrid and a lots of ToggleButtons) in the C# code and filled them into the UI when needed.

This is actually a huge overhead for the system and it is not convenient to debug."

This is not true. Either thru xaml or C#, object creation shouldn't cause slowdowns since both of them will have to create the object either thru the usage of `new` or reflection or some other form object instantiation.

Comment: @Richard Zhang - MSFT I added var data = (sender as ToggleButton).DataContext as Apartment; and changed item to RoomGridView.ItemsSource = data.Rooms; but it doesn't show the rooms then. Did i get this wrong?   Also I have basic Staggered Panel Working but how do i make it adaptive? I'd need fixed Column Count 16 and fixed Rowcount 5, but resizing when the window is resizing. With UniformGrid this is a piece of cake but unfortunatly Uniform Grid doesn't have this fancy virtualization thing. heres What i got so far:

Comment: <GridView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource RoomItemTemplate}"
          x:Name="RoomGridView" 
                  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
            <GridView.ItemsPanel >
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <controls:StaggeredPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
       </GridView>

Comment: @Richard Zhang Ah Ok I need it in the Data Templates Togglebuttons Click event. Still i think it's a long way to make the Ui adaptive with fixed culumn and Row Count. Some more hints would be great. Thanks

Comment: Hi @sensn, If you have special requirements for `UniformGrid` (such as fixed rows and columns), you can directly replace `StaggeredPanel` with `UniformGrid`. `<ItemsPanelTemplate><controls:UniformGrid Columns="6" Rows="15" /></ItemsPanelTemplate>`

Comment: @Richard Zhang - MSFT That was easier than I thought. very cool. So I think now I've got everything to port my little app to this technique. Thanks  a lot!

Comment: @Richard Zhang - MSFT Sorry, but I just noticed that there is still the same laggy behaviour with this technique. if i create 80 buttons there is a lag when switching between apartments. I think thats just because of the Binding itself. because in my original programm where i update every button with ischecked= true/false in a loop there is no lag.  Demo of your  Gridviewtechnique now here : https://github.com/sensn/MSMVVM

Comment: @sensn Hi, I replaced the `GridView` with an `ItemsControl` and it looks like there is no delay, I have modified my answer and you can see its structure at the end.

Comment: @Richard Zhang - MSFT Alright! This is what I was looking for. So I'm going to mark your answer as the accepted answer to this problem. Thanks!